# Why my code doesn't work? (using multi expressions + cast + case)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

My column's example:

```
          (name) as varchar(50)
              s01
              s02
              s16
```

I want to Select first missing panelname above 0 also with using case and cast(in my example desired select will be 's03')

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT name 
    FROM customers 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 0
) 

SELECT  CASE WHEN cast(min(right(name, 2) + 1) as varchar(50)) < 10 THEN 's0' ELSE 's' END + 
        cast(min(right(name, 2) + 1) as varchar(50)) 
FROM cte 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT name 
    FROM customers  
    WHERE cast(right(customers.name, 2) as varchar(50)) = cast(right(cte.name, 2) as varchar(50))+1)
```

This code works but only in case when my table is null or table contains only numbers.

Example my columns in name-> Result will be s03

```
             1     or   101    
             2          102
             16         116
```

But when it contain letter

```
 example my columns in name
             s01         
             s02
             s016
```

It doesnt work. I get an error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 's01' to data type int. Should I put somewhere else cast to varchar?

Comment: Any suggestions? Or its better using other code for what i want to do?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant table DDL and sample data as DML.

Comment: I edit my question to be more specific. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see this question is tagged Sql Server 2000. Sql Server 2000 is **way** past end of life. It no longer gets any patches, even for critical security issues, and hasn't for some time now. Continuing to use it is highly irresponsible. Upgrading this server is job 1. This is also the reason your code won't work. CTEs were not added to Sql Server until Sql Server 2005.

Comment: @Joel: looks like the OP has switched tags to the 2005 version.

Comment: That's not really any better. Sql Server 2005 is end of life now, too (as of April 12 of this year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

It was need just to convert the union select.

```
    WITH cte AS(
    SELECT name 
    FROM customers 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CAST(0 AS VARCHAR(50)) 
    FROM INVENTORYPANELCAPTIONS
) 

SELECT  CASE WHEN  cast(min(right(name, 2) + 1) as varchar(50)) < 10 THEN 's0' ELSE 's' END 
        + cast(min(right(name, 2) + 1) as varchar(50)) 
FROM cte 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT name 
    FROM customers 
    WHERE right(customers.name, 2)= right(cte.name, 2)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing string (varchar) with int values, so try to cast varchar numbers to int instead of varchar before you're comparing them with int values or doing some operations with them

Maybe something like this (not sure if this will work, but just wrote it as example how the solution could look):

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT panelname FROM inventorypanelcaptions UNION ALL SELECT 0) 
SELECT CASE WHEN min(cast(right(panelname, 2) as int)) + 1 < 10 THEN 'o0' ELSE 'o' + cast(min(cast(right(panelname, 2) as int)) + 1 as varchar(50)) END
FROM cte 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT panelname FROM inventorypanelcaptions WHERE cast(right(inventorypanelcaptions.panelname, 2) as int) = cast(right(cte.panelname, 2) as int) + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But i m getting the same error. PLS HELP!

Comment: I still getting same error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'o01' to data type int.

Comment: Same error...I think the is somewhere else. You want to go in personal chat?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't right now because I need to go, but I can try later when I'll come back, but check what I wrote above the code (about casting numbers to int), maybe I missed something in your query

Comment: And try: SELECT right(panelname, 2) FROM inventorypanelcaptions ... CAST can have issues if you're not using varchar or nvarchar as data type because the last 2 characters don't have to be numbers in that case (I assumed for SQL example that you are using varchar or nvarchar)

Comment: My column is to varchar(50) why should i use int?  example o04 as varchar(50). Am i wrong?

Comment: Well, in your SQL query, you use CAST to get the number from varchar and the result of that is in varchar format and you compare varchar to int (what is like checking if string is equal to int), so any integers that are in varchar / nvarchar have to be converted to int if you want to do any operations like addition or any comparing

Comment: When you go back pls help me if you can. I' m above computer at least half day in thisThank you onve again for you help!